# Scroll issue in android native app

Tags: javascript, android, scroll, appium

I am using appium and java to automate my app. I need to scroll in a page till a specific text/Element. I am struggling since two days and have tried many solutions but it dint work. Listing down all the solutions and scenarios:

Appium version: 1.4.0
Java-client version : 4.1.2
Driver: RemoteWebDriver

Solution1.1:
Tried with Java Script. Here is the code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
HashMap scrollObjects = new HashMap();
scrollObjects.put("direction", "down");
scrollObjects.put("text", "Yes");
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObjects)
```

Solution 1.2:

```
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id =           'com.practo.fabric:id/toolbar']/following-sibling::android.widget.LinearLayout"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
HashMap scrollObjects = new HashMap();
scrollObjects.put("direction", "down");
scrollObjects.put("text", "Yes");
scrollObjects.put("element",wb);
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObjects);
```

Problem here is i dont have list view. I have linear layout so have tried with providing linear layout xpath also once but with no luck.

Solution2:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Dimension size =driver.manage().window().getSize();     
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80); 
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
int startx = size.width / 2; 
driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000); 
System.out.println("swiping is done ");
```

Here driver.swipe is giving error as i am RemoteWebDriver. When i try to use AndroidDriver it says deprecated.

what should i do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issue because of the appium server and java client library version mismatch. Kindly update appium server to 1.5/1.6 else you can use java-client library version 2.1.0.

If you choose to use java-client2.1.0 with appium 1.4 we are having a method named "scrollTo" which scrolls to a particular text. I have also used "swipe" as you mentioned in solution 2 in this combo.

```
driver.scrollTo("Like"); //Scrolls to Like text in the app
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by using AppiumDriver from java-client. As i am using latest java-client version (5.0.0-BETA6) it says "swipe" methos is deprecated. but it works.

```
driver.swipe(300, 701, 300, 441, 3000);
```

solved it using TouchAction class also.

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);   
action.press(300, 701).waitAction(2000).moveTo(300, 441).release();
action.perform();
```

Note: coordinates are hard coded.